Issue with std::filesystem::path conversion to std::string in C++
I'm facing an issue while attempting to fetch all filenames from a directory. The problem arises when handling certain strings, resulting in errors. Below is the code snippet:
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    const char* dir = "D:\\Music";
    std::vector<std::string> musicList;

    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(dir))
    {
        if (entry.is_regular_file())
        {
            musicList.emplace_back(entry.path().string());
        }
    }
}

The issue occurs at entry.path().string() when processing strings like L"D:\\Music\\suki\\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.mp3". The program terminates with an error pointing to:
_STD_BEGIN
// We would really love to use the proper way of building error_code by specializing
// is_error_code_enum and make_error_code for __std_win_error, but because:
//   1. We would like to keep the definition of __std_win_error in xfilesystem_abi.h
//   2. and xfilesystem_abi.h cannot include <system_error>
//   3. and specialization of is_error_code_enum and overload of make_error_code
//      need to be kept together with the enum (see limerick in N4950 [temp.expl.spec]/8)
// we resort to using this _Make_ec helper.
_NODISCARD inline error_code _Make_ec(__std_win_error _Errno) noexcept { // make an error_code
    return { static_cast<int>(_Errno), _STD system_category() };
}

[[noreturn]] inline void _Throw_system_error_from_std_win_error(const __std_win_error _Errno) {
    _THROW(system_error{ _Make_ec(_Errno) });  // Here occur error!
}
_STD_END

I compiled the code in Visual Studio 2022, and the C++ standard is C++17.
Upon investigation, I simplified the issue with:
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path = L"・";
    auto str = path.string();
}

Similar issues arose at path.string(). Upon further simplification using L"\u30FB", I discovered the character ・ is represented as "\u30FB".
While path.wstring(), path.u8string(), and other string conversions work well, I need a char* for APIs such as ImGui::Text(str) or FMOD's API. Attempts to convert wstring to string using codecvt, Win32 API, or ICU resulted in garbled text like "ãƒ»":
#include <filesystem>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, str.data(), len, nullptr, nullptr);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path = L"\u30FB";
    auto str = ws2s(path.wstring());
}

The resulting str was "ãƒ»" instead of "\u30FB".
Is there a reliable method to handle this situation effectively?

Okay, I found the issue. It's the encoding used in the VS debug interface. It doesn't display UTF-8 properly. For example, the contents of my vector<string> are in UTF-8, but the debug interface shows garbled text, like the content of vec[0]. All I need to do is append ,s8 to vec[0] in the watch window. This forces the debug display to show UTF-8 content correctly.
Oh Microsoft, why do you insist on UTF-16? Isn't UTF-8 good enough?

What encoding is ImGui::Text expecting? Does it even support non-ascii characters? If it's expecting utf-8 why not just use path.u8string()?

Yes, ImGui wants UTF-8. Be sure to load the correct glyphs into your fonts because it doesn't by default.

When you are checking a std::string that you think contains UTF-8 don't check it by printing it out, that often doesn't print correctly, especially on Windows. Instead look at the actual bytes (in a debugger say) and see if they are the expected UTF-8 encoding.

You say the text is "garbled", but it's exactly what I would expect to see for representation of a non-ASCII character in UTF-8 rendered in the standard Windows code page.

"I need a char* for APIs such as ImGui::Text(str)" - you can use u8string().c_str() to get a UTF-8 encoded char*. On a side note: your ws2s() function has a memory leak. You need to delete[] the char[] array you are allocating before return'ing the std::string.  Best to simply not allocate a char[] at all, you can instead presize your std::string and then convert directly into its memory buffer using the non-const std::string::data() method.

@Alan Birtles std::filesystem::path path(L"\u30FB"); auto u8str = path.u8string(); ImGui::Text(u8str.c_str()); I'm getting garbled characters in u8str and displaying '?' in ImGui. Perhaps I need to include the appropriate ttf in ImGui::IO, but u8str still shows garbled characters (in the debugger).

@john Oh, actually during debugging, I found that the result of path.string() is garbled

@Remy Lebeau Yeah, u8string works well, but the problem is, how do I convert char8_t* to char* for use in APIs?Oh, thanks for reminding me about the ws2s function. Actually, this was generated by ChatGPT, and I didn't look closely. It's really not rigorous enough, haha.

@guruguru a simple typecast from char8_t* to char* will suffice.

@Remy Lebeau Indeed, I tried const char8_t* ch8 = u8"\u1234"; char* ch = (char*)ch8; and it worked well. std::u8string u8str = u8"\u1234"; std::string str = (char*)u8str.c_str(); also worked fine like this.

@guruguru you should use reinterpret_cast instead of a C-style cast (especially since you are casting away constness!), eg: const char* ch = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ch8);. But anyway, in the latter case, I would use either std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(u8str.c_str()), u8str.size()); or std::string str(u8str.begin(), u8str.end()); instead. Though you don't really need the std::string at all: std::u8string u8str = u8"\u1234"; const char* ch = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(u8str.c_str());

@Remy Lebeau Indeed, that's true. But can I use const char* ch = std::bit_cast<const char*>(ch8);?

@guruguru I'm not experienced with bit_cast, so I can't answer that.

The program crashes since std::filesystem::path::string throws an exception and your code does not catch it.
This is a problem with encoding. Add this at the beginning of your program and the issue should be resolved:
static constexpr char localeName[] = "ja_JP.utf-8";

// Instruct the C standard library that Japanese will be used with UTF-8 encoding
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, localeName);

// Instruct the C++ standard library that Japanese will be used with UTF-8 encoding, for example in std::string, std::ostream
std::locale::global(std::locale(localeName));

// Use the system locale (language and encoding) when printing data to std::cout
// Note that if your system is using a different encoding than UTF-8, like CP932, the C++ standard library will implicitly do a conversion.
std::cout.imbue(std::locale{""});

I had a similar problem with boost::filesystem::path and this resolved the issues.
Note that the encoding part is most important. On MSVC, this should address the issue too:
static constexpr char localeName[] = ".utf-8";
Here is full demo, with this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <locale>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << #x " = " << x << '\n'

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale{".utf-8"});
    // use system encoding - language neutral
    std::locale sysLoc{std::locale{"C"}, "", std::locale::ctype};
    std::cout.imbue(sysLoc);
    std::cerr.imbue(sysLoc);
    
    for (const auto& dir_en : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{"."})
    {
        LOG(dir_en);
        LOG(dir_en.path());
        LOG(dir_en.path().string());
        std::cout << "---------------\n";
    }
}

I got this results:
C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5608-EF1A

 Directory of C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir

07/16/2024  03:58 PM    <DIR>          .
07/16/2024  03:58 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/16/2024  03:56 PM                47 Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt
07/16/2024  03:55 PM               526 main.cpp
               2 File(s)            573 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,074,545,664 bytes free

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>cl /std:c++20 /EHcs /O2 /D NDEBUG /utf-8 main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.39.33523 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33523.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>chcp
Active code page: 852

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>main.exe
dir_en = ".\\Angel Note - ????????.txt"
dir_en.path() = ".\\Angel Note - ????????.txt"
dir_en.path().string() = .\Angel Note - ????????.txt
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.cpp
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.exe
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.obj
---------------

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>main.exe
dir_en = ".\\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt"
dir_en.path() = ".\\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt"
dir_en.path().string() = .\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.cpp
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.exe
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.obj
---------------

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>chcp 932
Active code page: 932

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\MyDir>main.exe
dir_en = ".\\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt"
dir_en.path() = ".\\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt"
dir_en.path().string() = .\Angel Note - 月明かりは優しく・・・.txt
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.cpp"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.cpp
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.exe"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.exe
---------------
dir_en = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path() = ".\\main.obj"
dir_en.path().string() = .\main.obj
---------------

Note that when my code page do not support Japanese characters ? is printed (no crash). After I've change code page to 65001 (which represent UTF-8) proper Japanese characters are printed. It also works perfectly when Japanese code page 932 is used.

Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and it runs very well without throwing any exceptions. However, there is still a small issue. When I inspect the string converted from path.string() in the debugger, I find that it is still garbled, even though the characters in path display correctly.

Additionally, I have another question. I used Japanese characters, so I need to set ja_JP.utf-8. What if the string contains multiple languages, such as Korean or others? Furthermore, some filenames might contain non-UTF-8 characters, such as those encoded in GBK. How should I handle this? How can I correctly process a text set containing multiple character encodings?

Important part is .utf-8 which defines encoding which is able to cover all possible Unicode characters, so should work for all languages. In your case  ja_JP part is unimportant. It has impact on things like lexicographical sorting, printing floats or currency, date and so on.

On Windows with MSVC static constexpr char localeName[] = ".utf-8"; will work, but on POSIX systems this locale won't be parsed properly (sadly there is difference in locale naming between platforms).

This approach can only solve the issue cross-platform, but I'm currently not concerned about platforms other than Windows. Perhaps I could use Win32 to address this problem, but I'm not familiar with Win32, and the way C++ handles it is straightforward. Right now, a minor issue is that path.string() results in garbled text in the debug environment, though I haven't tried outputting its results yet, so I'm not sure if it will have any impact.

I've mention other platforms just in case. Just try this I'm sure it will work.

All right. I will try to do.

@guruguru see answer update. I run this code on my machine.

Oh, I got the same result on my computer. It handles quite well. It's actually just a console encoding issue. Setting it to UTF-8 makes it display correctly, and using setlocale prevents runtime exceptions. I tried applying your solution with the FMOD API, which passed in garbled text (I checked the values in the debugger), but it still worked fine (playing music). I suspect it might be an encoding problem with the VS debug page, causing garbled display of debug contents, whereas using wstring displays it correctly.And it's actually better to use UTF-16 for passing parameters in the Win API.
